# What is the purpose of using clustered keywords after primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key

This is driving me nuts, can someone tell me what is the purpose of using clustered keywords after primary key in MySQL? In which condition I have to use it? Does it depend on the primary key data type?

Example:

```
create table Orders
(
    OrderID int not null auto_increment,
    CustID smallint not null, -- FK Customers table
    EmpID smallint not null, -- FK Employees table
    constraint pk_Orders primary key clustered (OrderID asc)
);
```

Tnx in advance.

Comment: "I thought that in MySql a primary key will be a clustered index by default." @LukStorms Thats "half" true InnoDB engine uses indeed clustered indexes. MyISAM engine does not do that..  Nowadays InnoDB engine is MySQL default table engine..

Comment: This question looks to be mixing MySQL and SQL-server syntax together .. MySQL does not support a clustered keyword option and SQL server does not support AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 1):

SQL will create an index on default on primary key column.

Index is used similairly as you use index in a book - you want to look-up something in a book, you look at an index to see where it occurs in a book.

Obviously, you could find that without an index, but it would be extremely slow.

So, index is something, that will speed up queries. 
**A clustered index (SQL Server, MySQL/InnoDB) is a table stored in an index B-Tree structure. There is no second data structure (heap-table) for the table.**

Non-clustered index has no effect on how data is stored, it just has informations where to find particular row based on indexed column.

More can be found here: [Clustered Index / Non-Clustered Index](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/clustered-index)

Comment: "clustered index means that the data is stored in database accordingly to order of column, which has an index." This might be the case in SQL server but not in MySQL.